# Showing an equation is an invariant manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to show this? Thanks!

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = x $

$ \frac{dy}{dt} = 2x^2 $

Show that x = 0 and y = $ x^2 - 2 $ , are invariant manifolds for the vector field.

Comment: In case you have nothing else in mind, why not solving the equations first?

Comment: i thought you had to show that the manifold is tangent to the vector field

Comment: Exactly, one way (in case you don't know any other, you don't say anything about what you tried... you really should), is what I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no mathematician, but following the Wikipedia entry on an invariant manifold, we can say that $x=0$ is an invariant manifold because $\frac{dx}{dt}$ remains $0$ for $x=0$. As for the parabola $y=x^2-2$, take the time derivative of $y-x^2-2$ and show that it equals to zero.
$$\frac{d}{dt}(y-x^2-2)=0$$
I hope this helps.